# Lisp - List of lists with variable size

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have to represent a board game using lisp. To do that i have to create a function that builds the board.

This function receives an integer that represents the number of sublist the original list as to have. each one of this sublists have a different size growing in 3*n proportion. 
As an example ifthe function is called with the number 3, it will create a list with 3 sublists, the first with 3 position, the second with six and the third with 9.

Also, each of the positions need to be initialized with ´*.

To do this i think i have to make a recursive call to make-list, but i can't seem to do that right. i'be tried to use the 'dotimes' cycle to do that, but i didn't have any sucess with that.

So far i have:

```
(defun faz-tabuleiro (n_aneis)
    (make-list n_aneis :initial-element (...)
```

Wich creates the main list, but how can i represent the sublists inside with the right size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
(defun make-table (n)
  (loop :for i :from 1 :to n
        :collect (make-list (* i 3) :initial-element "*")))
```

Comment: if questions are possible homework, it is good tradition not to give a full solution...

Comment: @Rainer Joswig - the homework tag was only added after I'd given my answer.

Comment: True, but his wording made it obvious: 'I have to ...' vs. 'I want to...'.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig - you're reading a lot into the word 'have', especially considering the questioner probably isn't a native English speaker. I don't think it was at all obvious that this was homework when I answered the question, the question makes no mention of homework, classes, assignments, school or college.

Comment: It was my mistake, as Luke said, i'm not an native English speaker,i'm Portuguese. I will take more care in the future and add the homework tag.

Answer (score 3):

Map over a list of numbers being the length of the sublists. Use a function for this mapping which returns the right list initialized with the initial element.